# Android GCM / Listview updating

Tags: android, listview

I am currently displaying a list of items for users to upvote and downvote based on the amount they like that item.

Say for instance there are 3 different items, Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, each has 0 votes on it. When I upvote on one item, I would like it to go above the other and if I downvote it go below the other one. I got this to work perfectly through a list adapter and a custom class that extends BaseAdapter, the only problem I have now is that, if I'm on my own client and I upvote an item while a different user also is upvoting an item, it will refresh my list and it won't show that the local user clicked the item anymore so they can vote unlimited amount of times.

I currently have 2 Arraylists, one with all of the items, and one with only the items that are clicked and whether they were upvoted or downvoted.
I thought possibly calling .notifyDataSetChanged() would fix the issue, but currently it just isn't working.

I use GCM currently to send the host user a message saying their was an upvote or downvote, the main host upvotes / downvotes the item and sends the new list to all of the other clients.

If any code would be necessary to see just ask, thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you send the whole new list? Maybe if you would send only the modified entry (identified by some UID) and its action (up/down) you could perform the update locally whenever a message is received instead of overriding the existing list with the received one

Comment: @Lablabla I had thought about that but how would I make sure that the host and the user are seeing the same list

Comment: It depends, how are you making sure that this happen right now? How are the `Task`s originally shared? if they are local and new ones, when created, are sent to others and 'appear', you might consider a server (you probably have one for the GCM) to sync

Comment: @Lablabla I do have a server, currently have an arraylist of items in the list that I turn into one long string, encode it, compress it, and then send it through the server to the GCM script which sends it to the other user to decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send only the relevant entry and an action on it and allow the receiving side to update its own database.

I think the proper way of doing this is creating an object for each task. Each with its own UID (I used a number in the example, but it needs to be unique, so maybe a different way is better).

Then you have several operations on these object which happens locally and needs to be sent to the server, for example.

- Add new task will send to your server

  ```
  { "data": {
      "uid": "1",
      "operation": "new"
      "task": "task1String"
  }
  ```

  and the receiving side would add this to its own database
- Up/down voting a task will send to your server

  ```
  { "data": {
      "uid": "1",
      "operation": "upvote" / "downvote"
  }
  ```

  and this way the receiving side would know to change the vote of the task identified by the UID 1
- ...

Hope it helps.